# Posting from a mobile login form to a desktop page and returning the information

Tags: php, authentication, desktop

I have got a login form that was made by the previous IT Manager, I am learning PHP, Javascript etc as I am going along. I have got the first page login.php to recognise when a mobile device is being used to view the page and then to redirect the user to a mobile login page. 
The mobile login page has the same login sections but with mobile CSS/JQ code attached. 
I need to send the information submitted from mobile_login.php to login.php, login then to validate the login request and then return the information back to mobile_login.php with either the successful login, failed login or sms validation code required. 
The desktop login.php has these functions already in the coding of the page but we do not want to copy the code on multiple pages if I can send it from mobile_login.php to login,php.

```
  <form id='loginForm' name='loginForm' action='' method='POST'>
        <h3 style='margin-left:20px;'>Log In</h3>
        <div id='formDiv'>
            <div id='userInput'>
                <label for='user'>Username:</label>
                <INPUT TYPE=text name='user' value='<?php echo $user;?>' />
        </div>
        <div id='passInput'>
            <label for='pass'>Password:</label>
            <INPUT TYPE=password name='pass'/>
        </div>
        <div id='smsvalidationcode' <?php echo 
  ($smsvalidation?"":"style='display:none;'");?>>
            <label for='pass'>Validation Code:</label>
            <INPUT TYPE='NUMBER' pattern='\d*' name='smsvalidationcode'/>
        </div>
        <div style='clear:both;'></div>
        <input type='checkbox' name='forgottenpassword'><span 
 id='forgottenPasswordText'>Forgotten Password?</span>
        <div style='clear:both;'></div>
        <span id='changePass'><input type='checkbox' 
     name='changepassword'><span id='forgottenPasswordText'>Change 
     password after login.</span></span>
    </div>

    <input type='submit' id='loginButton' value='Log In'>
     </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can share some advices to you, it can be nise and helpful:

The main, you can use at least `include` in your PHP script. So in your case you can write an additional script file `do_login.php` where you should out all of validation and logging-in logic. 
And then in both of your page-scripts `login.php` and `mobile_login.php` in some of first code lines add the line

```
include "do_login.php";
```

In case of putting this "business-logic" file to some subdirectory restricted from direct web access, like for ex. "/engine" - write path to file too, like such

```
include "engine/do_login.php";
```

The second, do the next steps of making you a great coder by reading about and experimenting with [PHP Classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) and [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) architecture. It's great things.

And the last one small but pretty part - use same *lower case* for HTML tags and properties. Clean code is great holidays for any eyes including your own.

Additional small hint: if you need make php-block in your template with just `echo` - you can use `<?= ... ?>` instead of `<?php echo ... ?>`

Wish you'll success and good luck!

Comment: This is great, thank you, i'm shocked that I didnt think of that sooner, now all I have to do is make it look pretty :D

Comment: Nice to hear! So, you can select this answer as decision of your question, StackOverflow likes this :)